# Как получить значение?

Tags: python

Имею вот такой список:

```
[('User_206449445', 4), ('User_519508571', 3), ('User_348873498', 3),('User_305741077', 1), ('User_307657132', 1)]
```

как получить каждый элемент допустим `[0]` и получить его значение,а именно 4

Answer (score 1):

Сначала обращайтесь к элементу списка по индексу, затем к элементам выбранного элемента, так же по индексу:

```
In [2]: lst
Out[2]: 
[('User_206449445', 4),
 ('User_519508571', 3),
 ('User_348873498', 3),
 ('User_305741077', 1),
 ('User_307657132', 1)]

In [3]: lst[0][1]
Out[3]: 4

In [4]: lst[1][1]
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: lst[1][0]
Out[5]: 'User_519508571'

In [6]: for i in lst:
   ...:     print(i[1])
   ...:     
4
3
3
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать словарь с этими элементами, если необходим вывод значения по ключу

```
x = dict([('User_206449445', 4),
          ('User_519508571', 3),
          ('User_348873498', 3),
          ('User_305741077', 1),
          ('User_307657132', 1)])

print(x['User_206449445'])
# вывод значения по индексу 'User_206449445'
# 4

for v in x.values():
    print(v)
# вывод всех значений
# 4
# 3
# 3
# 1
# 1
```